# Why does query take so long inside of Firestore function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It seems to me, when inside a function, a query that would be quite fast when calling from javascript takes a lot of time.  This is regardless of the whether there are lots of records or none.  For example the following query always takes around 2-4 seconds, no matter if theres 1000 records or 0.  Anyone have any insight on what I may be doing wrong?

```
    exports.getDate = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  addCors(req, res, function () {
    console.log(1)
    getUserIDFromToken(req.body.userToken).then(function (user) {
      console.log(2)
      db.collection("date").where('user', '==', user.user_id).where("expired", "==", false).get().then(snapshot => {
        console.log(3)
```

Comment: How are you benchmarking the performance of your code?

Comment: you may have slow internet connection

Comment: @DougStevenson I am doing extensive logging inside the function that I can then see in the firebase console.  It is showing that this exact query takes 2-3 seconds every single time.

Comment: Can you show the entire code that you used for benchmarking, so we can all understand what exactly is being measured here?  Also, how are you invoking the function?  Are you benchmarking just a single call, or have you done repeated calls in a single function?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated the code in my initial post with something simplified to what I've been doing.  I'm logging out more in my actual code.  But the jist is that I log it out and then view it in the functions console on the firebase console.  I can then see when each portion is triggered and how long it's execution takes.  I am invoking the function as a service.  Each call is made once, but no matter how many times i do it in a row it's never performant.